# Django-cms PlaceholderField in custom plugin, used in Placeholder, not front-end editable

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I am using the 2.2 django-cms on django 1.3, as well as the 2.3 django-cms git repo on django 1.4, and I notice that if I include a PlaceholderField in my model such as this:

```
##books/models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    description = cmsmodels.PlaceholderField('book_description', null=True, blank=True)

class BookCMSPluginModelItem(models.Model):
    t_book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    ...

class BookCMSPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    featured_books = models.ManyToManyField(BookCMSPluginModelItem)
    template = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices= settings.BOOKS_TEMPLATES, default=settings.BOOKS_TEMPLATES[0]);
```

and make my CMS Plugin like so:

```
##books/cms_plugins.py
class BookCMSPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = BookCMSPluginModel
    name = _("Books Plugin")
    
    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        self.render_template = instance.template;
        context['instance'] = instance;
        return context
```

Then in my template at some point I discover I can do the following:

```
{% for mitem in instance.featured_books.all %}
    <!-- ...... -->
<div>{% render_placeholder mitem.t_book.description %}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

BUT, in the front end editor, I add my new plugin, and the description field does show up as a placeholder, **however when I hover over it, the outer placeholder I placed the plugin into is active, and I cannot select directly the inner placeholder**.  It works quite well in the admin site, as I can add content using SemanticEditor and whatever else I wish to use.  **In the front-end, however, there's a frustrating issue with the javascript that seems to prevent the user from adding or editing the inner placeholder.**

I should note that I followed the wonderful django-cms documentation here: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/placeholders.html, but that site only addresses the issue in the context of displaying a model in a specifically designed page, unfortunately not using a template for a custom django-cms plugin.

Comment: I've got the same problem with django-cms 3.0.0beta2. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Same problem here with 3.0.6

Comment: Seems to still be an issue with 3.1.0

Answer (score 2):

In [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/2244#issuecomment-39678256) one of the django-cms developers says that there is no plugin-in-plugin architecture in Django CMS 2.2.

I've tried it with the latest development branch and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with

```
Django==3.1.6
django-cms==3.8.0
python_version = 3.6.9
```

One unrecommended workaround is to change cms source code at 1 place

Go to `virtualenvs/your-project-vitualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/models`

then edit the file `placeholdermodel`

got to line #123 `Placeholder.has_change_permission` and comment the first if-return.

=> Comment line #132 `if not attached_models:`
=> and line #136 `return user.is_superuser`

Save it and restart your server.

```py
def has_change_permission(self, user):
    """
    Returns True if user has permission
    to change all models attached to this placeholder.
    """
    from cms.utils.permissions import get_model_permission_codename

    attached_models = self._get_attached_models()
    
    # Comment this part!
    # if not attached_models:
    #     # technically if placeholder is not attached to anything,
    #     # user should not be able to change it but if is superuser
    #     # then we "should" allow it.
    #     return user.is_superuser

    attached_objects = self._get_attached_objects()

    for obj in attached_objects:
        try:
            perm = obj.has_placeholder_change_permission(user)
        except AttributeError:
            model = type(obj)
            change_perm = get_model_permission_codename(model, 'change')
            perm = user.has_perm(change_perm)

        if not perm:
            return False
    return True
```